# Swift Overload init()

Tags: xcode, swift, overloading, init

i will overload the init Method in Swift how i can implement that?

here my code that not work

code removed

Edit:

So it would be work fine

```
override init() {
    super.init();
}

init(title:String?) {
    super.init();
    self.title = title
}

convenience init(title:String?, imageName:String?) {
    self.init(title:title)
    self.imageName = imageName
}

convenience init(title:String?, imageName:String?, contentKey:String?) {
    self.init(title:title, imageName:imageName)
    self.contentKey = contentKey
}
```

Comment: What does not't work exactly? What errors are you getting? I guess you need to provide values for any new properties introduced by the class. And then call `super.init()`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

***Updated Answer***

```
class Y { }
class X : Y {
    var title: String?
    var imageName: String?

    convenience override init() {
        self.init(title: nil, imageName: nil)
    }

    convenience init(title:String?) {
        self.init(title: title, imageName: nil)
    }

    init(title: String?, imageName: String?) {
        self.title = title
        self.imageName = imageName
        super.init()
    }
}
```

- Use the most complete initializer as the designated initializer.

  In this case `init(title: String?, imageName: String?)` is the only initializer that sets all its properties, so it should be the designated initializer.
- Initialize your properties before calling `super.init()`.

  My old answer only worked because `title` and `imageName` were both `var` and optional.

  In Two-Phase Initialization section of [The Swift Programming Language: Initialization](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html)

  > #### Safety check 1
  >
  > A designated initializer must ensure that all of the properties introduced by its class are initialized before it delegates up to a superclass initializer.

---

***Old Answer***

I plugged the sample into a playground, here is how I got it to work:

```
class Y { }
class X : Y {
    var title: String?
    var imageName: String?

    override init() {

    }

    init(aTitle:String?) {
        super.init()
        self.title = aTitle
    }

    convenience init(aTitle:String?, aImageName:String?) {
        self.init(aTitle: aTitle)
        self.imageName = aImageName
    }
}
```

- `init(aTitle:String?, aImageName:String?)` cannot call `init(aTitle:)` and still be a designated initializer, it must be a convenience initializer.
- `self.init` must be before anything else in `init(aTitle:String?, aImageName:String?)`.
- initializer must be passed the parameter name `self.init(aTitle)` must be `self.init(aTitle: aTitle)`.

As a side note, I removed the unneeded semicolons and put `super.init()` first for style reasons.

Hope that helps.

---

**UPDATE**

To follow Apple's advice, there should only be one designated, the rest should be convenience initializers. For example, if you decide `init(aTitle:String?)` should be the designated initializer, then the code should look like:

```
convenience override init() {
    self.init(aTitle: nil) // A convenience initializer calls the designated initializer.
}

init(aTitle:String?) {
    super.init() // Only the designated initializer calls super.init.
    self.title = aTitle
}

convenience init(aTitle:String?, aImageName:String?) {
    self.init(aTitle: aTitle)  // A convenience initializer calls the designated initializer.
    self.imageName = aImageName
}
```

There are times when you might want more than once designated initializer, for example, `UIView`, but that should be an exception, not the rule.

---

**UPDATE 2**

Classes should have one designated initializer. Convenience initializer will (eventually) call the the designated initializer.

[Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Initialization.html)

> A class may have multiple initializers. This occurs when the initialization data can take varied forms or where certain initializers, as a matter of convenience, supply default values. In this case, **one of the initialization methods is called the designated initializer**, which takes the full complement of initialization parameters.

[Multiple initializers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MultipleInitializers.html)

> #### The Designated Initializer
>
> The initializer of a class that takes the full complement of initialization parameters is usually the designated initializer. The designated initializer of a subclass must invoke the designated initializer of its superclass by sending a message to super. **The convenience (or secondary) initializers—which can include init—do not call super.** Instead they call (through a message to self) the initializer in the series with the next most parameters, supplying a default value for the parameter not passed into it. **The final initializer in this series is the designated initializer.**

Comment: Thanks that works when i have more overloaded init i must write allways convenience

override init() {
        super.init();
    }
    
    init(title:String?) {
        super.init();
        self.title = title
    }
    
    convenience init(title:String?, imageName:String?) {
        self.init(title:title)
        self.imageName = imageName
    }
    
    convenience init(title:String?, imageName:String?, contentKey:String?) {
        self.init(title:title, imageName:imageName)
        self.contentKey = contentKey
    }

Comment: There are two kinds of initializers: designated and convenience. If at all possible, you want to only have 1 designated initializer, all others should be convenience initializers (see: [Designated Initializers and Convenience Initializers](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_325)).

Comment: Fail, this does nothing

Comment: @JefferyThomas could you please provide a link to the Apple's advice where is mentioned that there should be only one designated initializer? This claim doesn't sound right to me. Thanks

Comment: @0101 I cited my source.

Comment: @JefferyThomas thank you. In quotations above is however not mentioned that there can be / should be **only one** designated initializer. The quotations are also rather obj-c oriented. If you look at Swift 2.2 docs (Designated Initializers and Convenience Initializers) you'll see "*Every class must have at least one designated initializer.*" and "*Classes tend to have very few designated initializers, and it is quite common for a class to have only one*"...

Comment: @0101 Apple clearly intends programmers to use the fewest possible designated initializers, one being the ideal number. In the reference I cited, it is assumed there would be only one. In the reference you cited, they state, "it is quite common for a class to have only one". Given all this, I think it's fair to say, a class should only have one designated initializer, unless you have a good reason for more.